# My Own Implementation Of PrintStream for Testing

Tags: java, testing, printstream

I have a class which does the following

```
class PersonDumper {

    // attributes

    public PersonDumper(PrintStream output, Set<Person> persons) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public dump() {
        for(Person p : persons) {
            output.print(p);
            output.print(",");
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I want to test that the formatting I am giving to the Person objects (in the example I want to print the toString() method), and so on is right.

Then I would like to test the output with something like this:

```
public class ListPrintStream extends PrintStream {
    private List<List<String>> output;
    // every time I call to print I do output.add(string)
}
```

Then, I can get that List> and read it in order to test if I am outputting what I want.

But I have problems with the constructor used for PrintStream. Because, in my case, I don't want any argument for the constructor.

Do you think that I am using a good approach?
Shall I use the OutputStream class instead of PrintStream?
Any hint?

Edit to ask:

Does anyone know a PrintStream that is used for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a dummy output stream to the superclass constructor, such as the [NullOutputStream from Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html), which is an OutputStream implementation that silently discards all data written to it.

Alternatively, you could consider declaring your `PersonDumper` to take an instance of `Appendable` instead.  `PrintStream` implements `Appendable` so this won't change your code in the normal case, but for testing you could pass in a `StringBuilder` or similar instead.

```
class PersonDumper {

    // attributes

    public PersonDumper(Appendable output, Set<Person> persons) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public dump() {
        for(Person p : persons) {
            // String.valueOf rather than .toString to be null-safe
            output.append(String.valueOf(p));
            output.append(",");
        }
    }
}
```